# Conditional Normal Distribution of Mice

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

The weights of a population of mice fed a certain diet follow a normal distribution with mean $\mu=100$ grams and standard deviation $\sigma=20$ grams. A random sample of $8$ such mice is taken.
Let $X_1$ denote the number of mice with weights between $80$ and $100$ grams.
Let $X_2$ denote the number with weights above $100$ grams.
I have to find $E(X_2|X_1=2)$ and Var$(X_2|X_1=2)$.

I know the formula for $E(X_2|X_1=2)$ = $\mu_2 + {p\sigma_2\over\sigma_1}(x_1-\mu_1)$. The only thing that gets me is that there is a sample of $8$ mice so I don't know how I would find $\mu_1, \mu_2, \sigma_1, and \sigma_2$. Would I do that $\mu_1={(80+100)\over 2}=90$, but I feel like that can't be right since it is a normal distribution. and little $x_1=2$, which would be the number of mice having nothing to do with the mean, so I'm a little confused. Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think that, conditionally on $X_{1}=2$, the random variable $X_{2}$ has
a binomial distribution.

Condition $X_{1}=2$ can be interpreted as:
we are looking at $6$ mice here and the weight of each of them is
smaller than $80$ or larger than $100$. Indeed we started by taking $8$ mice, but $2$ of them where 'uninteresting' because their weight did not fall in one of these categories. This tells us that $X_{2}$ conditionally on $X_{1}=2$ has the distribution $\text{Bin}\left(6,p\right)$ for

$p=P\left(W>100\mid W<80\vee W>100\right)=\frac{P\left(W>100\right)}{P\left(W<80\right)+P\left(W>100\right)}$
where $W\sim N\left(100,400\right)$.

It is evident that $P\left(W>100\right)=\frac{1}{2}$
so $p=\frac{1}{2P\left(W<80\right)+1}$. This $p$ can be calculated.

Then $E\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}=2\right)=6p$
and $\text{var }\left(X_{2}\mid X_{1}=2\right)=6p(1-p)$.

Comment: +1. However you seem to believe that something like $(X\mid Y=y)$ is well defined and is a random variable. It is not, hence I rephrased in the standard terminology the relevant places in your post.

Comment: @did thank you for your adaptions. I will leave it like this. Not a well defined random variable? Well..., I am not so sure yet, but I will think about that.

Comment: @Did It was too big for a comment so I made it a question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/534910/75923