# Why $X\mid Y=y$ is not a random variable?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and let $X,Y$ two random variable on $\Omega $. I was wondering why $X|Y=y$ is not a random variable ? (I know it is if $Y$ is discrete, but why not in the general cases ?). For example, I would think that $X|Y=y$ is the random variable density function $f_{X|Y=y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ as far as $X,Y$ has good condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random variable is defined to be a measurable function function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ where $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$ is a probability space and $\mathbb R$ is equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra of Borelsets.

In $(X\mid Y=y)$ we *cannot recognize* a function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. Not even if $Y$ is discrete. If $P(Y=y)>0$ then at most we can say that $(X\mid Y=y)$ induces some probability measure $Q$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ characterized by: $$A\mapsto\frac{P(A\cap\{ Y=y\})}{P(Y=y)}$$for $A\in\mathcal A$.

Observe that: $$Q(\{X\in B\})=P(X\in B\mid Y=y)$$

In this situation (i.e. $P(Y=y)>0$) it is actually only the "definition" of random variable that withholds us from saying that $X\mid Y=y$ is a random variable.

In my view another definition is possible that takes away that barrier, but who am I to provide in a definition of random variable...

To see what I mean by that have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534910/75923) of myself about the same topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also see your link, but I still don't understand why $(X\mid Y=y)$ is not a function $\Omega \to \mathbb R$. If $y$ is fixed, It would be natural to define it as $(X\mid Y=y)(\omega )=(X(\omega )|Y=y)$, no ?

Comment: But what is the meaning of $X(\omega)\mid Y=y$ where $X(\omega)$ is nothing else but a real number? How can a condition like $Y=y$ have any affect on a fixed real number? If it really is function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$ then what is its value for $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. But what about defining $X|Y=y$ as the random variable of density $f_{X|Y=y}$ ? We know that if $f_{X\mid Y=y}$ is a density function, we can construct a r.v. on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ (if $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is big enough) with density $\int_{-\infty }^x f_{X|Y=y}(u)du$. Why not denoting $X|Y=y$ this r.v. ?

Comment: Well, then you start with a distribution and on base of the distribution you construct a random variable with the special property that it has this distribution. This however cannot be done on a canonical way: lots of rv's can be constructed on several ways that have the distribution, so which one to choose? And secondly: what is the use of it? We can use the distribution anyhow, without constructing some rv that has this distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer :) (I'll probably ask you a question in your link a bit later, because I'm not sure to understand why $X\mid Y=y$ would be a r.v. in $(\Omega ,\mathcal A,Q,X)$.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Just a very last thing. Let $X_i$ random variable, and $N$ a random variable on $\mathbb N$. Set $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i$. In this special case, is $S_N|N=n$ a random variable ? I would interpret it as $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Comment: Counterpoint: When $P(Y=y)>0$, then $X|(Y=y)$ **is** a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,Q)$, where $Q(A)=P(A|Y=y)$. Furthermore, even when $P(Y=y)=0$, as long as $y\in \operatorname{supp} Y$, then we can think of $X|(Y=y)$ as a random variable on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B_{\mathbb R},\mu)$, where the measurable function is the identity function, and $$P(X\le x|Y=y)=\mu((-\infty, x])=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{P\Big(X\le x\cap Y\in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\Big)}{P(Y\in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon))}.
$$
This is essentially thinking of $P(X\in A|Y=y)$ as a regular conditional distribution.

Comment: Furthermore, there is good reason to want to do this; if $(X,Y)$ are jointly normal, it totally makes sense to say that $X|Y=y$ is normal. Also, this is how we think of the Brownian bridge.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y = y]$ is a random variable on a coarser probability space. In particular, it's a measurable map from $\sigma(Y=y)\subset\Omega$, where $\sigma(Y=y)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra\[\{E\cap \{\omega:Y(\omega)=y\}: E\in\Omega\}.\]

This measurable map from $\sigma(Y=y)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as
\[
\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y](E) = \int_E X \,d\mathbb{P}
\]

If you have not seen a measure-theoretic definition of conditional expectation before, there should be one in any probability textbook. The [conditional expectation wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition) has an ok formal definition but it is very terse.

You might also be interested in [regular conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability).

Comment: $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is indeed a random variable, but $\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$ is not.

Comment: Not sure to understand. $\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$ is a deterministic r.v., may be you talk about $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ ? Now, the law of $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is not really clear as far as $X$ is non $\sigma (Y)-$measurable, no ? To conclude, $f_{X|Y=y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ would be the density of which r.v. if it's not the density of $X|Y=y$ ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to talk about $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y]$ instead of $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$. My mistake!