# Conditioning a "general" random variable on a discrete one

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability

Suppose we have random variables $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow (\Omega_{X}, \mathcal{F}_{X})$ and $W:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{N}_{n}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_n))$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}_n = \mathbb{N} \cap [1, n]$.

I can see a way of defining $X \vert W=w$, which I will denote by $X_w$, for $w \in \mathbb{N}_n$.

Let $E_w = W^{-1}(\{w\})$ and $\mathcal{F}_w = \{A \cap E_{w}:A \in \mathcal{F}\}$. Assume that $\mathbb{P}(E_w) > 0$. Define $\mathbb{P_w: \mathcal{F}_{w} \rightarrow [0, 1]}, A \mapsto \mathbb{P}(A \vert E_w)$.

One defines $X_w:(E_w, \mathcal{F}_w, \mathbb{P}_w) \rightarrow (\Omega_X, \mathcal{F}_X), x \mapsto X(x)$.

This seems to be a "natural" way to define this conditional random variable, but its causing me some unexpected surprises in my work. It may be the case that the surprises are just something I will have to deal with.

Has anyone seen an alternative way to think about this?

Comment: If I understand well then you are constructing a probability space and define a random variable on that space in such a way that its distribution is the same as the distribution of $X$ under condition $W=w$. Is that correct? A question that arises then is: "Why doing this? Is knowledge of the distribution on its own not enough for many many things already? Do we really *need* a random variable that *has* that distribution?" [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534910/75923) (of myself) and its answers might interest you.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing. I see your point about there not actually being a need to define $X_w$, but that one can just work with the conditional distribution. I've given this a shot and it produces the same surprising result as before, but the formulation is more "natural". So this looks to be a wall to climb, rather than walk around. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad I could help you in this. As you can see - following the link in my former comment - I am familiar myself with that wall that must be climbed. Cheers!